# Заполнение связанных таблиц начальными данными Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Доброго времени суток.

Имеются 2 сущности, где вторая зависит от первой:

```
public class Region
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

В классе `public sealed class ApplicationContext : DbContext` определен конструктор:

```
public ApplicationContext() => Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Также в нем переопределен метод:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Region[] regions = ... ;

    City[] cities = ... ;

    modelBuilder.Entity<Region>().HasData(regions);
    modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasData(cities);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

После вызова конструктора приложение падает с ошибкой:

System.InvalidOperationException: "The seed entity for entity type 'City' with the key value 'Id:1' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Region' set. To seed relationships you need to add the related entity seed to 'Region' and specify the foreign key values {'RegionId'}."

В связи с чем у меня несколько вопросов:

1. Самый главный: в чем проблема, что я делаю не так и как это
   исправить?
2. Немного не по теме, но все же: что будет с данными в базе
   и с ней самой, если сервер вдруг упадет? Останутся ли они на месте
   или удалятся при остановке сервера?

Comment: а метод HasData() принимает массив разве?

Comment: Второй вопрос почти никакого отношения к первому, и к ef вообще не имеет - если хотите знать, что происходит при падении sql server - стоит оформить отдельный вопрос

Comment: попробуйте задать данные таким способом: `modelBuilder.Entity<Racer>().HasData(
        new Racer { Id = 1, Name = "Lewis Hamilton", Team = "Mercedes" },
        new Racer { Id = 2, Name = "Sebastian Vettel", Team = "Ferrari" }
    );` сначала таблицу `Region` а потом `City`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц но я ведь в такой последовательности и добавляю. В принципе, ваш подход схож с этим: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/2.14.php . Единственное различие в моем коде - это то, что данные я заношу в переменную, т.к. их более 2,5 тыс.

Answer (score 0):

На первый взгляд в схеме данных нет связей к этим таблицам, по поводу второго вопроса  - если данные в "кеше", то их не будет, если данные в таблице, то они останутся и основное - делать резервное копирование базы(если это возможно).

Comment: Я делал в соответствии со статьей https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.1.php . Я так понял, что поле для внешнего ключа можно опустить и оставить только навигационное свойство (в моем случае `Region`)

Comment: это все меняет, Смотрите диаграмму, там что - то со значениями связей будет не так...даже ошибка ссылается на значение id = 1 не соответствует значение Региона....

Answer (score 0):

*To seed relationships you need to add the related entity seed to 'Region' and specify the foreign key values {'RegionId'}.*

Весь ответ в ошибке - что бы добавить связанные сущности нужно помимо навигационного свойства добавить внешний ключ, то есть одно без другого не работает.